# I am looking to understand vectors

Tags: vectors

I am trying to learn intro calculus.

I am wondering if this proof is correct for vector.

If we have some vector function , r(t) and say that the length of this vector is a constant, say 1, then is it always the case we will have r'(t) being perpendicular to r(t)?

To me this seems like it might me true, but I do not understand it geometrically.

The proof I am writing I am also unsure if it is fully valid.

Proof:

I took the fact that $r(t) \bullet r(t)= ||r(t)||^{2}=c^{2}$

but I am not sure where to go exactly next. Im thinking I should use the derivative?

My first time so hopefully the formatting came out well, I used the guide.

Comment: That's a good start.  The next step is to take the derivative of both sides of that equation -- make sure you remember to do the product rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is so far a good start. And using the derivative is the right idea,
you could write , because $c^{2}$ is also just a constant,

$0=d/dt[r(t) \bullet r(t)] , = r'(t) \bullet r(t) + r(t) \bullet r'(t)= 2 r'(t) \bullet r(t)$

so you have the dot product is equal to 0, thus they are always orthogonal!

Answer (score 0):

also, to make sure the vector formalism becomes intuitively transparent, see it in co-ordinates, with $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 = c
$$
also:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} = \sum_k \dot x_k\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}
$$
hence:
$$
2\sum_k \dot x_k x_k = 0
$$
i.e.
$$
\dot x \bullet x= 0
$$